# Complex batch process {read-write-split-enrich-write}

Tags: spring-batch

I have such situation - I have a file where every line consists of a name either of file or directory and operation status. This file may contain thousands of lines. 
Then I should write name either of file or dir and its status to db. Finally, I have to write to a new file, BUT if an item is a directory I have to find all files from this directory and write names of these files instead of the directory name.

I see this as two step job when the first step is to read from the file and then write to db and parallelly save items as in-memory list. The second step is to read from this in-memory list and if this is directory substitute it with files names in a reader, then write to file.

One thing I worried about is to hold thousands of objects between steps.

Can anyone suggest more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two steps. You can use a single step.

- Your reader would remain same
- You expand directory to file using processor( or can be achieved in item reader as well)
- Use delegated Item writer and write to database and new file.

Here is sample Batch Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>();
        reader.setResource(new PathResource("MyFile"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemReader<String> cpReader(){
        final CompositeItemReader<String> reader = new CompositeItemReader<>();
        reader.setItemReader(reader());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<String> cpWriter(){
        final CompositeItemWriter<String> delegator = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        delegator.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(fileWriter(), dbWriter()));
        return cpWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<String> fileWriter(){
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<String> dbWriter(){
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<String> writer() {
        final ItemWriter<String> writer = new ItemWriter<String>() {

            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
                items.forEach(System.out::println);

            }
        };
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job kpJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("kpJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1Child").<String, String>chunk(10).reader(cpReader()).writer(cpWriter()).stream(reader()).build();
    }

}
```

The compositeItemReader

```
public class CompositeItemReader implements ItemCountAware, ItemReader<String> {

    private ItemReader<String> itemReader;
    private int count = 1;
    private final LinkedList<String> files = new LinkedList<>();

    public ItemReader<String> getItemReader() {
        return itemReader;
    }

    public void setItemReader(ItemReader<String> itemReader) {
        this.itemReader = itemReader;
    }

    @Override
    public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        return readFile();
    }

    private String readFile()
            throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if (files.size() == 0) {
            final String item = itemReader.read();
            if (item == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                Path path = Paths.get(item);
                if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                    files.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) Files.walk(path, 1).map(Path::toString)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

                } else {
                    files.add(path.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return files.poll();
    }

    @Override
    public void setItemCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;

    }

}
```

Hope this basic info gets going.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this? For example, I didn't get, as I have to write to db directory name and to file - expanded filenames for dir, how can I achieve this with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, if someone curious, I came to next solution: created in database new table for storing records from file as-is, thus if a line contains filename store it, if a line contains dirname store it too. Then with help of this table, I can do joins to my target table to take a list of filenames from a specific directory.

So, the first step is just read from file and store into two tables - new one and target one.

And the second step is to read from the database with a query that returns only filenames and just write these records to file without any splitting/enrichment because this had been done by the query.